# Putting sections in elementor in wordpress tabs on the same page

Tags: wordpress, tabs, elementor

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDr8S.jpg)

Putting sections in elementor in wordpress tabs on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create and save your section in the template,
Design your section as you need, then add an advanced tab or MA tabs in your page, in content settings click on tab effect and choose click option, then go to tab title in that click on content type choose saved section and add a section which you want.